# Indeces of duplicates in a numpy 3d array

Tags: python, image, numpy, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I have a 3d numpy array. Each of the 1000 rows is an  150x150 image.
Meaning that the input array has a shape (1000,150,150)

Some of these 1000 images  are duplicated.

The task is to find the unique images (based on the 150x150 pixel values) and all the indices where each unique image is present in the original dataframe.

I tried:
u, indices = np.unique(img, return_inverse=True)

but this is not what I am looking for: this would give me 256 different values from 0 to 255 which are the possible pixels level.

What I rather need is to split the 1000 indexes into  groups, each one having the same sequence of the 48x48 pixels.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Use `unique` with the `axis` kwd.

Comment: It works. Thank you